# Can I use the Deflect Arrows feat to deflect bullets shot from a firearm?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

[Deflect Arrows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deflect-arrows-combat) is a combat feat that allows to deflect projectiles once per round when I would normally be hit by the projectile. The only projectiles listed as non-deflectable are:

> Unusually massive ranged weapons (such as boulders or ballista bolts) and ranged attacks generated by natural attacks or spell effects

A bullet shot from a firearm has very low mass (even though velocity is likely high). I don't know of any bullets generated by natural attacks, nor by spell effects.

**So, did I get the rules right, can I really be *that* badass and deflect one bullet per round with one free hand?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Congratulations, you're -that- badass, as long as you're not facing a scatter weapon.**

[According to the firearm rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/firearms/) you're specifically eligible to deflect and snatch bullets:

> **Deflecting and Snatching Bullets**: The Deflect Arrows feat and the Snatch Arrows feat can be used to deflect bullets, but not pellets shot from a scatter weapon. Neither of these feats can be used to deflect siege firearm attacks.